# How to change DataTables row color

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table draw by DataTables. For every rows, last column of the table is a buttom which shows other jquery element (bxslider in my case, but it does not matter here). I want to be able to **change the color of a row when I click on it buttom**. I found some solutions but these only change the color before draw a DataTable, not running when a DataTables is draw already.

The buttoms have the html class "onclick".

I draw a datatable as follows:

> `$(div).DataTable({"data" : dataSet, "columns": columns})`

Haw can I do that?

Thank you, regards.
Mike

Comment: Show some CODE also. So, we can help you further.

Comment: I write something else but I don't know what code do you need. My JS code run against the webpage, there is not more code which envolves the DataTables I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will something like this work?

```js
//initialise datatables on DOM load
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});

//on clicking the row
$("tbody tr").on("click", function() {
  //loop through all td elements in the row
  $(this).find("td").each(function(i) {
    //toggle between adding/removing the 'active' class
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Set !important rule to override default colors */
.active {
  background: gold !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes! That was what I was looking for. Thank you a lot. I'm going to modify  it a little bit according what I want to do but the idea is very nice.

Comment: @Miguel.G great, i just added an update right before your comment that will colour all columns including the first one.

Comment: Nice, you again yoda thank. (as Yoda speaks, I know this is not very funny lol)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#dataTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
    });
```